# Which item is returned from Intersect, the one from first or from second enumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an item object:

```
class Item : IEquatable<Item>
{
   public string Id { get; }
   public string Name { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Item);
    }

    public bool Equals(Item other)
    {
        return other != null && Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 2108858624 + Id.GetHashCode();
    }   
}
```

Doing the intersection:

```
Item[] items1 = new Item[] { new Item() { Id = 1, Name = 1 } };
Item[] items2 = new Item[] { new Item() { Id = 1, Name = 2 } };

IEnumerable<Item> intersection = items1.Intersect(items2).ToList();
```

it shows that it chooses item with `Name = 1`.

My question is it guaranteed that `Intersect` always chooses items from the first enumerable and not the second? I could not find any information about which instance does `Intersect` exactly chooses.

**I realize since two items are equal, I should not need to know which instance is chosen by `Intersect`. But here's my scenario:**

Imagine a scenario where there are items stored in the app locally and they need to be merged with items coming from a backend. An online item with same id might have `Name` updated, but it's still "same item" with an item stored locally. That's why is important to understand which instance does `Intersect` chooses.

So maybe my problem is somewhere else?

.NET allows us to override what "equality" between two objects means. However, when using `Intersect` and other LINQ stuff, things seem a bit blurry to me.

Comment: Even if the current implementation always returns the first, this is not guaranteed to never change. If it's not documented, treat it as unspecified and subject to change.

Comment: If two items having the same Id and a different Name aren't considered equal, then don't claim they are equal. In other words, your comparison claims the objects are equal, so why would it matter which one would be returned? Intersect() might not be the way to go for synchronization logic.

Comment: @CodeCaster I fully agree with you. If two items are equal I shouldn't be concerned nor need which one is chosen. That's why I wrote the last paragraph where I explain why I need this. So please read the whole question. Maybe I am missing something else in my logic, maybe there's a problem somewhere else. Can you point what the problem is?

Comment: The point is that you're writing synchronization logic. The item with Id X can be edited locally _and_ on the server, causing a conflict. You need a different marker than just the Id, and a resolution strategy. Like version numbers or edit-datetimes. Intersect() isn't the solution, and thus the question is moot, IMHO.

Comment: Even if it seems to be guaranteed because it is documented, remember that you or your colleagues will forget this fact. So document it yourself. You have a hidden logic now.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't understand what you mean by "the question is moot". What's the solution you're suggesting? I think I described the problem well, there shouldn't be any misunderstanding

Comment: Your problem is: you have local items and remote items. They can be out of sync, and you want to determine which items are out of sync. You use Intersect() for that, but that is not the right tool for the job. So no matter what answer you get to this question, it won't solve your problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster: imo OP says that the items can be changed only remotely, then i don't see why it's bad to use this logic. Its a simply and efficient approach. He wants to guarantee that on merge(intersect) one source is used, thus this is an important and interesting question.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's my conclusion too, I already posted minutes ago in a comment. I don't think LINQ stuff like `Intersect` is the right tool when it's important to know the instance, because LINQ is using IEquatable<T>. When using LINQ you shouldn't care about actual instance, because LINQ is based on IEquatable.
Finding yourself needing to know which instance it is, should be an indication something is wrong in the logic

Comment: @DonBox: i don't understand how `IEquatable<T>` is relevant here. The question is if `Intersect` always returns the item from the first collection and never from the second. If something is documented you can rely on it. And here its guaranteed that OP will always get the item from the desired collection and never from the (possibly) outdated, so the merge will always contain the right items.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My conclusion so far is the question is actually wrong. `Intersect`'s *only* job is to give you an enumerable with the intersection. It guarantees that the result is found in both enumerables you used as an input. Which means if you actually go and take each object in the returned enumerable you will find it *equals* to one of the objects in both the enumerables.

Comment: @DonBox: if you want to know which instance is outdated you need a diffferent way of  course. If you feel like you don't want to merge them because they are not really equal, use a different `IEqualityComparer<T>` for `Intersect`. There's an overload which enables you to passs a custom comparer. You don't need to modify the `Item` class itself.

Comment: @TimSchmelter How would a custom comparer would help? IEqualityComparer has a boolean method, which says yes or no, it doesn't return an actual instance. Can you post a concrete example? Remember I need to have an actual list of items. Let's say I want to know which local items are the same with items received from backend. My conclusion now is that `Intersect` cannot help me with this.

Comment: @DonBox: i still don't understand why Intersect doesn't help you when you want all  local items  which are the same with items received from backend. You want only items that are really equal, so also the `Name` or you want to know which item has changed?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to know which items changed so I can update the local versions. I cannot just override local ones with ones fetched from backend because there's some merge logic which needs to happen, otherwise I could override local ones which were changed locally.

Comment: What I do is, I take each item received from backend (let's call it online items), find it locally, and if it exists then update the local one with the online one in a specific way.

Comment: @DonBox: i have posted an answer. But please don't accept it ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks. I did accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little bit off-topic from question which [Zohar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50620207/284240) has already answered. But  OP said in a comment:

> Let's say I want to know which local items are
>   the same with items received from backend. My conclusion now is that
>   `Intersect` cannot help me with this.  I want to know which items changed so I 
>   can update the local versions. I cannot just override local ones with
>   ones fetched from backend because there's some merge logic which needs
>   to happen, otherwise I could override local ones which were changed
>   locally

Well, that's a different requirement than what you have mentioned in the question(merge and take from one source) and `Intersect` really doesn't help much.

```
var changedNameItems = from l in localItems
                       join o in onlineItems
                       on l.Id equals o.Id
                       where l.Name != o.Name
                       select new{ LocalItem = l, OnlineItem = o };

foreach(var x in changedNameItems)
{
    // if you want to change the local item's name:
    x.LocalItem.Name = x.OnlineItem.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs):

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
        if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
        if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
        return IntersectIterator<TSource>(first, second, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
    {
        if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
        if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
        return IntersectIterator<TSource>(first, second, comparer);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
    {
        Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
        foreach (TSource element in second) set.Add(element);
        foreach (TSource element in first)
            if (set.Remove(element)) yield return element;
    }
```

As you can see, it returns the elements from the first set that matches the elements in the second set.

However, as Tim rightfully wrote - the source code is not a binding contract. This behavior might change in future versions, so it's best not to rely on the source code as a guarantee.

Please note that it's also documented in the remarks section of the [`Enumerable.Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Intersect__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) Method Microsoft Docs page:

> The intersection of two sets A and B is defined as the set that contains **all the elements of A** that also appear in B, but no other elements.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Source code isn't a contract, there's no guarantee that the implementation won't change in future. Only documentation or specification ensures that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter correct. I've edited my answer (found the relevant part in the documentation)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Before asking the question here, I actually went and read on msdn. I too saw that paragraph in Remarks. I am not convinced that the paragraph actually refers to the implementation. It looks like the intersect definition in mathematics.

Comment: The problem I am seeing and its where it gets confusing is, .NET allows us to override what equality means. In the same time, when it comes to LINQ stuff like Intersect, Union, etc. if you really need to know the instance, this doesn't look right. I am starting to feel like using LINQ when you need to know the instance is the wrong tool, because LINQ uses IEquatable<T> that's the whole point after all

Comment: @DonBox Well, if you are not satisfied with the documentation, but understand the source code, you can always just copy it to your own method, to protect your code against possible changes in future versions of .Net...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Copy and duplicate the implementation? I don't think that's a good thing to do.

Comment: Why not? You said you don't trust Microsoft will not change the implementation. You know the current implementation does what you want, it is an open source, and I think it's safe to say it's well-written, so I don't see the problem with duplicating the current implementation.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Duplicating code just to be sure Microsoft doesn't change it is weird to me. It smells like you're doing something (else) wrong.

Comment: You are the one that said you don't think the documentation guarantees it will not change, not me... It might smell bad but what other choice do you have if you don't trust the documentation?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think the choice is to just not use `Intersect` when you care about actual instances, because that's not what `Intersect` does, what it does is to give you an intersection which is guaranteed to have objects which can be *found* in both enumerables.